# How can i get the string between html commetns start end with regular expression ?

Tags: php, html, regex

I wan to get he text between the HTML comments start and end Like

```
<!--Q1-->
\nフレンチブルドックと遊んでるとき\n
<!--Q1END-->\n
<!--Q2-->
\n表参道、新宿、銀座\n
<!--Q2END-->\n
<!--Q3-->
\nヒューマンドラマ全般が好きです。<BR>\n<BR>\n好きなアーティスト　サザンオールスターズ\n
<!--Q3END-->
```

I want to get it as array like this

```
$data = [
 1 => 'フレンチブルドックと遊んでるとき',
 2 => '表参道、新宿、銀座',
 3 = 'ヒューマンドラマ全般が好きです。<BR>\n<BR>\n好きなアーティスト　サザンオールスター  ズ'
]
```

So how can i find the text between html comments ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Mike currently I am using `strpos()` and `substr()` to find that, But i want to get this with regular expressions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that would get you what you want for the above string:

```
/<!--Q(\d)-->\n\\n(.*)\\n\n<!--Q\1END-->/gs
```

(Note: This removes the literal `'\n'` before and after each of the strings you want since this is what you have above, but if the strings don't have this, it won't match either.)

To put that into PHP remember you have to double escape the literal backslashes. Unfortunately it's quite ugly to keep track of all the newlines and literal `'\n'` strings (at least to me).

```
preg_match_all('/<!--Q(\d)-->\n\\\\n(.*)\\\\n\n<!--Q\1END-->/s', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[2]);
```

Or if you want something more readable, you can remove the literal `'\n'` strings from the input text, match everything between the HTML quotes and then trim it:

```
// Remove all literal '\n' strings from the text
$text = preg_replace('#\\\\n#', '', $text);

// Match desired strings
preg_match_all('/<!--Q(\d)-->(.*)<!--Q\1END-->/s', $text, $matches);

// Trim all desired strings
$output = array_map('trim', $matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get  literally what you want lookarounds are good option:

```
(?<=<!--([A-Z]\d)-->)[\s\S]*?(?=<!--\1END-->)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/GakkMg/1)

Caveat: Works as long as your comment keys (e.g. `Q1`) do not exceed A0-Z9. You cannot simply use `[A-Z]\d+` instead since PHP's/PCRE regex engine does not like quantifiers/variable length patterns in lookbehinds.

Otherwise, I recommend using a capture group like this:

```
<!--([A-Z]\d+)-->([\s\S]*?)<!--\1END-->
```

Use it in your code like this:

```
$re = '/<!--([A-Z]\d+)-->([\s\S]*?)<!--\1END-->/s';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

To get rid of the newline, just use `trim()`, there are several ways to apply it, e.g. a foreach, a map, etc.

```
foreach ($matches as $match){
  $result[] = trim($match[2]);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: It would appear the desired output does not contain the literal `'\n'` strings or newlines.